# Profiling high CPU usage (with Nodetime) on my Node.js app running on Amazon ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage, load-testing

I have been trying to do some load testing (using BlazeMeter) on my node.js app running on an amazon ec2. I started testing with 500 users hitting my endpoint on the t2.Micro but this soon collapsed (maxing both memory and CPU). I tried similar test on the t2.Small, t2.Medium and c3.large, with all of these tests, the memory was fine but I would end up maxing CPU and eventually response times would get above 60 seconds and I would get a 504 Gateway timeout from nginx.

I have tried profiling my app with Nodetime but nothing looks very strange:

[image]

It doesn't seem like any of the listed tasks is using much CPU but top tells me that the CPU (or CPUS running on c3.large) are totally maxed, and this leaves me a bit confused.

Am i reading this wrong?

EDIT:

Here is a screenshot of top showing node maxxing the CPU:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the output for top ?

Comment: @AdiDembak I added a screenshot of top maxxing out the CPU.

Comment: Note that MongoDB is also using some serious CPU here.  I would look at the areas in the application where Node interacts with Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try profiling for more time or on time when the CPU goes high.
Probably your profile time did not catch the peak CPU usage